# Play sound when Link Clicked

Tags: php, javascript, html, audio, hyperlink

I have written a small web application but am missing some cool functionality. I want to play a sound when the user clicks the link, but after playing the sound continues to navigate to the URL the link points to.

Any ideas?

Comment: I wonder how this will mesh with IE's similar (mis)feature - the Navigation Completed click.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While the pursuit of coolness is a worthy ideal, I would strongly recommend **against** playing a sound when a user clicks a link (or at any time!). As both a user and a web developer this would startle me right to the back button. Only several minutes later would I be witty enough to think that I just time traveled to the mid 1990's

EDIT

unless you're going for something retro, like this: (which i highly suspect you aren't)

http://www2.warnerbros.com/spacejam/movie/jam.htm

EDIT II

Hmm... well I guess a being a game changes things a little. I would recommend binding the click event with jquery to append a sound file to the dom, something like this:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $('body').append('<embed src="/path/to/your/sound.wav" autostart="true" hidden="true" loop="false">');
    pause(1000);   //Number of milliseconds to pause
    window.location = http://www.asdf.com //new url to go to
});
function pause(milliseconds) {
    var dt = new Date();
    while ((new Date()) - dt <= milliseconds) { /* Do nothing */ }
}
```

Comment: +1  How about a site with no sound?!  That sounds just about perfect to me.  First thing I do when I hear an unexpected sound on a site is look for the mute button!

Comment: It is a game like app, not a site. It has to have some sort of functionality.

Comment: Just make sure you don't have any other `embed` elements. :)

Comment: @Zachary Did the extra javascript help you with the question?

Answer (score 1):

Attach an onclick handler to the link with JavaScript. This function will need to:

1. Inject or activate a Flash movie or other object capable of playing the audio. JavaScript has no audio-generation abilities itself.
2. Start a timer to redirect to the link's original location after a suitable delay to load and play the sound. Use `window.location` to redirect the browser to the URL.
3. `return false` to stop the default click action (leaving the page) from occurring too fast for the sound to play.